# How to get signal from AKAI MPK Mini MK3 in Ableton Live 11 Suite

Tags: ableton-live

Just plugged in a new MPK Mini MK3. Opened Ableton Live 11 Suite, using the trial version not sure if that matters. See settings below and armed track. When touching the keys or any of the beat pads, there is no signal being shown in Ableton.

What else is required to have the signal from the MPK Mini available in Ableton? Any other details missing?

**MIDI settings:**
[image]

**Track is "armed"**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems to have been conflicting with other software. Just closed the following applications:

Adobe Premiere Pro CC
Adobe After Effects CC
OBS Studio
Adobe Audition

Hope this helps someone else. Try closing all other applications if you are not getting a signal.